# A question about nonmeasurable subset of real line and uncountable measure-zero subset.

Tags: real-analysis

When I was reviewing real analysis, I have a question below.

> Does every nonmeasurable subset of real line have an uncountable and measure-zero subset?

Just consider the [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure).

I have known that this is true for every measurable set whose measure is greater than zero.

Comment: Does "measurable" here mean Lebesgue measurable or Borel measurable?

Comment: @NateEldredge Lebesgue measure.

Comment: (For other readers: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050013/does-every-set-of-positive-measure-contain-an-uncountable-null-set) is a proof of the mentioned result for measurable sets.)

Comment: Please edit your question to include an actual question in some place other than the title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This cannot be answered by the usual axioms of set theory.**

- It's consistent with ZFC that every set of reals of size $\aleph_1$ has measure zero (note that this requires [$2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuum-hypothesis/)). For example, this follows from [MA$_{\aleph_1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_axiom). 
  In this case  if $A$ is non-measurable, just consider any subset of $A$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$.
- Meanwhile, a consistent negative answer is easy to construct via transfinite recursion assuming CH (these are the [Sierpinski sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_set)). The key point here is that, while there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$-many null sets in general, we can find a set $\mathcal{G}$ of $2^{\aleph_0}$-many *(hence by CH, $\aleph_1$-many)* null sets such that every null set is contained in one in $\mathcal{G}$, and this lets us set up a length-$\omega_1$  recursion *(length-$\omega_1$ is useful since it means that at each step we've only "used countably many points" so there are lots of points "still untouched" as we continue to build our set)*.

Finally, I don't know what happens if *both* CH and MA$_{\aleph_1}$ fail.

---

As an aside, note the crucial role in the first bulletpoint of the number $$\mathfrak{m}=\mbox{the least size of a non-measurable set}.$$ This "$2^{\aleph_0}$-like" number is a **cardinal characteristic of the continuum** - there's a lot of interesting mathematics around what we can (and can't!) prove about CCCs.

Comment: Honestly,I am inclined to think that CH(or GCH) is right.Set theory is very complicated.....

Comment: Indeed, in the second bullet we can take $\mathcal{G}$ to be the set of all measure-zero $G_\delta$ sets.

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis FWIW I tend to prefer $\neg CH$ - it makes the theory of cardinal characteristics nontrivial, and is compatible with various other fun shenanigans. But I go back and forth.

Comment: Adding $\aleph_1$ Cohen reals will always add a Luzin set. Or maybe Random reals. One of the two, I never remember which is which (the other adds a similar set for Baire).